# Can a possible subgraph contain a completely unconnected vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

If you have say, a square. Can a subgraph of that square be the top left vertex left alone with an order of 0, whilst the right-most and the bottom lines are included. Would that be valid? Or would it have to be only the left and right lines.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a subgraph can contain an isolated vertex.  You can have any subset of the vertices, and any subset of the edges, provided only that any vertices incident to the edges be in the subgraph.

Comment: And a disconnected graph can contain an isolated vertex?

Comment: @SamConnell: A single isolated vertex constitutes a _connected_ graph.

Comment: @SamConnell I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  An isolated vertex by itself is a connected graph.

Comment: If you have a square, if you take the single isolated vertex as the top left one, and have the other three vertices connected by the bottom and right lines of a square, would that be a valid disconnected subgraph?

Comment: @SamConnell Yes, it would.

Answer (score 1):

A **subgraph** of a graph $(V,E)$ is a graph $(V',E')$ where $V'\subseteq V$ and $E'\subseteq E$. For example it is even allowed to have $V'=V$ and $E'=\emptyset$. (But of course we can only have $vw\in E'$ if both $v\in V'$ and $w\in V'$).

What you are perhaps thinking of is an **induced subgraph**, that is a subgraph where $E'=\{\,vw\in E\mid v\in V', w\in V'\,\}$.